# Native Library Bindings File - incorrect path

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, vue-router, node-modules

I am trying to consume `pcsclite` (native library) from my app `sample-app` but then I am getting this error message:

```
[vue-router] Failed to resolve async component default: Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → C:\Users\mememe\Desktop\Electron\apps\sample-app\build\pcsclite.node
 → C:\Users\mememe\Desktop\Electron\apps\sample-app\build\Debug\pcsclite.node
 → C:\Users\mememe\Desktop\Electron\apps\sample-app\build\Release\pcsclite.node
 → C:\Users\mememe\Desktop\Electron\apps\sample-app\out\Debug\pcsclite.node
 → C:\Users\mememe\Desktop\Electron\apps\sample-app\Debug\pcsclite.node
 → C:\Users\mememe\Desktop\Electron\apps\sample-app\out\Release\pcsclite.node
 → C:\Users\mememe\Desktop\Electron\apps\sample-app\Release\pcsclite.node
 → C:\Users\mememe\Desktop\Electron\apps\sample-app\build\default\pcsclite.node
 → C:\Users\mememe\Desktop\Electron\apps\sample-app\compiled\12.18.3\win32\x64\pcsclite.node
 → C:\Users\mememe\Desktop\Electron\apps\sample-app\addon-build\release\install-root\pcsclite.node
 → C:\Users\mememe\Desktop\Electron\apps\sample-app\addon-build\debug\install-root\pcsclite.node
 → C:\Users\mememe\Desktop\Electron\apps\sample-app\addon-build\default\install-root\pcsclite.node
 → C:\Users\mememe\Desktop\Electron\apps\sample-app\lib\binding\node-v85-win32-x64\pcsclite.node
```

It looks like the `vue-router` is looking at the wrong path. It should be looking inside `node_modules\pcsclite\*` (like `node_modules\pcsclite\build`) but it looks directly at my project folder `sample-app\*` (like `sample-app\build`).

I am using Quasar framework for Electron app development.

How can I fix this issue??

Help please, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set your build path into asar-unpack. It'll include your build module files into the app file.

like this.

```
 "asarUnpack": [
    "./node_modules//lib/win32/**",
    "./node_modules/builds"
  ],
```

Answer (score -1):

Debug folder not secure for usage. Native modules are build into `./build/Release/*.node`. Please check your path.